# wlbs.exe command not found when running from a program that calls the system() API call

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have this strange issue only seen on Windows 2008.  On Windows 2003, I am running fine.

My C++ program will calls a bat file, using the system() command.   Inside the batch file, it will call the wlbs command.  However, when running the batch file from the program, I see the following error:

'wlbs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I echoed the %PATH% environment variable and see that C:\Windows\System32 is already there.

If I run the batch file from the same user account that I am starting the program from, on the command line, the batch file was able to invoke the command successfully.  I already selected the program to be ran as Administrator, and my login session is also administrator.

I updated the batch file to output the dir listing, like "dir C:\Windows\System32\*.exe > list.txt"  and surprisingly, in the list.txt, it was able to list out other exe except for the wlbs.exe (and I suspect a bunch of other exe were missing as well), when I run the batch file from my program.

However, when I run the batch file from the commandline, I was able to see the wlbs.exe from the list.txt generated from above.  It seems that the issue only happens if the batch file was invoked from the program.

I also attempt to update the file permission for C:\Windows\System32\wlbs.exe but the update options are disabled by default, despite that I am logged in as Administrator already on the system.

Any help on the above issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your windows 2008 server is probably a 64x system. In such system there are two different system32 folders. For 32 bit executable on 64 bit system the %systemroot%\syswow64 is what they see as %systemroot%\system32. Strange world.

For a quick fix, You can just copy the wlbs.exe program to the %systemroot%\syswow64 folder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your answer is helpful in pointing me to the right direction and after some research the binaries can be executed by referencing the path %SystemRoot%\sysnative\ directly.